# Client-server live stream using RPi camera using JAVA

Tags: java, video-streaming, vlc

I am trying to do live stream from RPi camera in java but I have problem because I am very new in this kind of programming and didn't find answer that would help me with this.

I have my server app from this page: [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/810004/Live-Video-from-Raspberry-Pi-to-NET)

It works with .NET but I want to do whole thing in Java(UDP version in my case). 
I was following documentation on [enter link description here](http://eneter.net/OnlineHelp/EneterMessagingFrameworkJava/index.html) but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code of the client app:

```
public class CamService {

public static IDuplexOutputChannel myVideoChannel;
public static String StreamAddr = "udp://192.168.0.145:8093/";
public static OutputStream myVideoStream;
public static BufferedOutputStream bOut;
public static String pName;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    JFrame frame;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "c:\\program files (x86)\\videolan\\vlc\\");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new UdpMessagingSystemFactory();


    myVideoChannel = aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel(StreamAddr);  
    myVideoChannel.responseMessageReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseMessageReceived);


    frame = new JFrame("AWWWW!");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();



    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            myVideoChannel.closeConnection();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });      

    frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    String[] mediaOptions = { 
            ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{preset=ultrafast},vb=512 }"
          + ":std{access=udp,mux=ts}"  };
    Media media = new SimpleMedia(StreamAddr, mediaOptions);
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(media);

    myVideoChannel.openConnection();
}

private static void onResponseMessageReceived(Object sender, DuplexChannelMessageEventArgs e) throws IOException 
 {

    byte[] aMessage = (byte[])e.getMessage();
    System.out.println("Byte message: " + aMessage);

    myVideoStream.write(aMessage, 0, aMessage.length);  
    bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(myVideoStream);

    System.out.println("Buffered Output: " + myVideoStream);
 }
private static EventHandler<DuplexChannelMessageEventArgs> myOnResponseMessageReceived = new EventHandler<DuplexChannelMessageEventArgs>()
 { 
     @Override       
     public void onEvent(Object sender, DuplexChannelMessageEventArgs e)
     {
        try {
            onResponseMessageReceived(sender, e);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("NOPE");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
        }           

     }
 };
```

}

I am not getting any errors while compiling it. It connects to server, turning on the camera but it doesn't stream it. After closing program i am getting:

> main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer

Would be very thankful for ANY help with this. 
Thanks.